# Scaling of Meta site's background images is completely wack on a 4K (3840×2160px) resolution display regardless of browser viewport dimensions

Tags: bug, design

For demonstration I snapped the browser window into a corner which makes it take up roughly a 1920x1080 rectangle, and this is how main and meta look like:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is probably a CSS bug with determining the screen space where desktop resolution is taken on meta and viewport size is taken on main. Main works fine, so it should be possible to copy the same code parts over to meta's CSS.

Answer (score 2):

At some point this apparently got fixed (either by SE or by Firefox's support of CSS, I can't tell) and now looks okay:

[image]